# Accessing JSON information from Rails in d3.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, d3.js

I'm trying to incorporate d3.js into my project and am having trouble figuring out how to access a JSON object, which is being served from my Ruby on Rails backend.

Here is my Controller code:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
respond_to :html, :json

def course
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  respond_with @course do |format|
    format.html
    format.json {render json: @course}
  end
end
```

I've been trying both in the console and in my view to figure out how to access the information. (by the way, if I scrap the respond_with block and just keep the render JSON block, I can see that the JSON object is, in fact, a response object).

Here is what I've been trying (in the view):

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var data  = d3.json('<%= @course %>');
  console.log(data);
<% end %>
```

This returns an object, but the object is undefined, so when I call:

```
dataset[0].course.course_name;
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'course' of undefined
```

I've also tried something like the following in the console:

```
var url = '/courses/1';
var dataset = d3.json(url);
dataset[0].course.course_name;
```

But get the same error.

I'm relatively new to js, so I'm likely making a rookie mistake, but, whatever it is, I can't see it!

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the d3.json function (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) with one parameter returns the request. You would then have to issue that request.

The 'typical' use is to have a second parameter, with a callback function. This is an asynchronous callback, so you can't assign the return value to a var.

Here is what I suggest:

```
var url = '/courses/1';
d3.json( url, function( error, data ) {
    console.log( data );
    // do all actions required now that the data is retrieved
} );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this was driving me nuts!